# Branch.io api update type. Make previously created link appear on quick links

Tags: api, branch.io

I created a bunch of links through the API without specifying the type which defaults to 0. This doesn't make the links show on the dashboard under quick links. Now, I would like to make them show there but there doesn't seem to be an option to add a quick link, only create new. Given this, my idea was to use the API to read and update it however, update doesn't seem to allow passing argument type. Any hints on how to overcome this?

I have made a get request, retrieving the whole link details, copied the result, added the branch_key and branch_secret, changed type from 0 to 2 and sent an update request.

I've opened the link with ?debug=true but it doesn't seem to be a way to edit it to make it show on quick links either.

Response code was:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid parameter: type"
    }
}
```

As soon as I remove the type parameter, I get the proper link response with all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that you saw is the expected behavior. The "type" key is reserved key and is not able to be changed once you created the link. You can manually set this only when you create the link using the API call. Please do reach out at integrations@branch.io if you have any further questions!

Answer (score 0):

We store API created links and quick links in different DBs due to the volume of each type. This means that it's actually impossible to create a quick link through our public API or SDK. The only place would be from the dashboard. :( Hopefully, you understand our reasoning for doing it this way.